How does the length of aging and the barrel type influence the taste of tequila?
While there are some additional varieties of tequila for the sake of my question, I'd like to focus on the three most common:
Blanco: Young tequila that is aged for 60 days or less.
Reposado: Tequila that has been aged for more than sixty days but less than a year.
Añejo: Tequila that has been aged for 1-3 years.
Different types of barrels are used. While blanco typically uses steel barrels, the more aged varieties of tequila use oak. I have two questions about the aging process and how that impacts the flavor.

Is there a drastic difference in a reposado that is aged for 3 months vs an 11 month reposado or a 1 year aged anejo vs one that has aged for 3 years? If there is what flavors or nodes would one expect to taste?

Does the barrel make a difference in the taste? So if a tequila was aged in a French Oak barrel vs an American Oak barrel for example, would that impact the taste?



Yes, there is a considerable difference in taste imparted by the length of time the spirit ages in the barrel. Similarly to whisky (or whiskey), tannins and resins in the wood leech into the spirit, increasing over time. And different types of woods have different quantities and types of these, so they all have a different impact on the final taste.
There are some aged tequilas that use barrels that were previously filled with port, bourbon or other liquids, and these also change the final flavour.
